# JSP--how to get request parameter

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, authentication

I have a login.jsp which gets submitted to index.jsp passing along the username and password params. How can i retrieve these params in index.jsp? The call to index.jsp is a POST request.

Not really a java guy...thanks

Comment: Did you try searching the site before posting this question?

Comment: Answer is available... [on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197046/is-there-a-request-context-in-java)

Comment: Every JSP has a `ServletRequest` parameter called `request`

Comment: no, i searched it after. I guess it was as simple as request.getParameter("paramname");

Answer (score 0):

You can do this!

```
public String getLoginForm(@RequestParam String username, 
                           @RequestParam String password)
{
//....
}
```

HTH!