# How do I put a Java object into a HttpSession and use it across all my packages?

Tags: java, servlets, global-variables, httpsession

I am developing a Java Web Application which consists of a lot of JSPs, JSs, Servelts, while business logic is handled in POJOs.

My need is to initiate a class inside my Servlet, and set is as a global variable, and use it throughout all the packages in my application.

Now, I have defined a few global variables using

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("<ATTR_NAME>", <MY_OBJECT>);
```

But what I am lacking here is I can use the value of this attribute only inside the Servlet, or in other words, places where I have access to HttpServletRequest.

I need a solution to define a global variable, and be able to use it in all my POJOs which contain my business logic, where I may not have access to HttpServletRequest. I also do not want to pass this global variable of mine from the Servlet to all these POJOs either through Constructors or method arguments.

I have gone through a few articles which spoke about ServletContext amongst other things, but I do not get a clear picture.

Any little help is highly appreceated.

Thanks,
Sriram Sridharan

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you store Java objects in HttpSession?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766521/how-do-you-store-java-objects-in-httpsession)

Comment: @abhijeetdhumal Not even close to being duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving Web Session from a POJO Outside the Web Container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764285/retrieving-web-session-from-a-pojo-outside-the-web-container)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you initiate a Java Bean in your base servlet and use it throughout the runtime?

```
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

private String name;
private Integer age;

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getAge(){
    return this.age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age){
    this.age = age;
}
```

}

Comment: Because they don't know how? Seems like that's the entire point of their question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I agree. The point is what do I do to make this bean visible even in places i don't have access to HttpServletRequest /HttpServletResponse?

Comment: @sriramsridharan Look out for Serialization

Answer (score -1):

One solution can be create a load-on-startup servlet which set the context as in the article in link [access context in DAO/POJO](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/J2EE/JSP/Q_27223173.html) or 
another solution is using filter as in link [session from pojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764285/retrieving-web-session-from-a-pojo-outside-the-web-container)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use some object in application context may use some context holder (singletone) and store object in the ServletContext's attributes:

Context holder:

```
public class CtxHolder {
    private static ServletContext ctx;
    private static Context nCtx;

    private DSHolder() {
    }

    public static void setCtx(ServletContext ctx) {
        DSHolder.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public static ServletContext getCtx() {
        if (ctx == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Need to set servlet context");
        }
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

Then define Servlet Context Listener and invoke CtxHolder.setCtx() (from contextInitialized() method) when application starts.

Then you can get/set "global" (application's scope) attributes as:

```
CtxHolder.getCtx().setAttribute("key", new Object());
```

But remember about synchronization! Each request processes in own thread.